# How to respond without reloading my current page?

Tags: node.js, api, express

I have Express API which used to upload file to the files directory. Whenever I call my API res.send redirecting to a new page. How can I  perform this API with reloading my current page?

```html
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  let sampleFile;
  let uploadPath;

  if (Object.keys(req.files).length == 0) {
    res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
    return;
  }

  console.log('req.files >>>', req.files); // eslint-disable-line


  sampleFile = req.files.sampleFile;
  console.log('lusu', sampleFile); // eslint-disable-line


  uploadPath = __dirname + '/uploads/' + sampleFile.name;

  sampleFile.mv(uploadPath, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }

    res.send('File uploaded to ' + uploadPath);
  });
});
```

Comment: how are you consuming this api in the frontend?

Comment: am using this file upload in my chat screen whenever i upload the file it will redirect to other page by leaving the chat screen :-(

Comment: What is your front end technology?

Comment: in the chat screen, if the request is some sort of a submit button that triggers a javascript event, you can use "event.preventDefault()" to prevent the default behavior of the submit button. that may stop the page reload

https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Take a look at that link

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to recommend multer package for file upload in node js.

---

instead of `res.send(), try res.status(200).json({message:"successfully uploaded"})`

---

try debugging at front end, suppose you have a function for file upload like below,

```
function fileUpload(){

http.post('url',{headers:headers}).then(res){

// Try to handle the response here. Do not write anything that reloads the page.

}

}
```

Comment: but why you recommending multer ?

Comment: `res.send({ message: "Success"})` would behave same as `res.status(200).json({message:"Success"})`!

Comment: @thillai they have written some extra things those you can use might just have a look at their js file you will get an Idea.